# AsWing JCombox, JList, JButton etc with custom skin

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swing, flashdevelop

I am using open source flash gui framework AsWing. I want to change the default skin of JButton, JList and JComboBox with my custom images.

is it possible? Any code reference ? How could i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look at [AsWing doc](http://doc.aswing.org/a3/), [setForegroundDecorator](http://doc.aswing.org/a3/org/aswing/Component.html#setForegroundDecorator%28%29) method will help you!